# Table inside a dynamic table accordion on clicking particular row

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html-table, accordion

In this code I have made a table inside a table, Which I am trying to populate the data inside a table, I am getting the data using PHP, but I need here accordion on clicking the particular row, the html written in Javascript should expand. On clicking a particular row I want that particular have to expand.

```
<div class="row" style="float:right; display: flex; margin-bottom:10px;">
   <p style="font-size: 18px; margin-right: 30px; "><b>Search </b> </p>
   <input type="text" id="search-payment-detail" style="margin-right: 5px;" class="form-control" />
   <a href="/admin/member-payment-detail" class="btn btn btn-primary btn-sm">Add Member Payment Detail</a>
</div>
{{--{{dd($payment_details)}}--}}
<div id="prefetched">
   <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Mobile</th>
            <th>Role</th>
            <th>Status</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         @foreach($payment_details as $payment_detail)
         <tr class="tableshow">
            <td>{{$payment_detail->sc_fullname}}</td>
            <td>{{$payment_detail->sc_email}}</td>
            <td>{{$payment_detail->sc_mobile_no}}</td>
            <td>{{$payment_detail->role}}</td>
            <td>{{$payment_detail->status}}</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="5" style="display:none" class="collapseshow">
               <table style="width:100%" class="table table-bordered">
                  @foreach($payment_detail->payementDetail as $pd)
                  <td class="width:100%">p1: {{$pd->p1}}</td>
                  <td>p2:{{$pd->p2}}</td>
                  <td>p3:{{$pd->p3}}</td>
                  <td>p4:{{$pd->p4}}</td>
                  <td>p5:{{$pd->p5}}</td>
                  <td>p6:{{$pd->p6}}</td>
                  <td>p7:{{$pd->p7}}</td>
                  <td>p8:{{$pd->p8}}</td>
                  <td>p9:{{$pd->p9}}</td>
                  <td>p10:{{$pd->p10}}</td>
                  <td>p11:{{$pd->p11}}</td>
                  <td>p12:{{$pd->p112}}</td>
                  <a href="/admin/edit-member-payment-detail/{{$pd->id}}">Edit</a>
                  <a href="/admin/delete-member-payment-detail/{{$pd->id}}">Delete</a>
                  @endforeach
               </table>
            </td>
            @endforeach
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
<div id="search-fetched"></div>
@endsection
@section('scripts')
<script>
   $('#search-payment-detail').keyup(function () {
       if ($.trim($('#search-payment-detail').val())) {
           $.get('/admin/search-member-payment-detail', {info: $('#search-payment-detail').val()}, function (data) {
               var html = `<div><table class="table table-bordered">
                 <thead>
                  <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Email</th>
                   <th>Mobile</th>
                   <th>Role</th>
                   <th>Status</th>
                   </tr>
                   </thead>`;
               for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                   html += `
                      <tr>
                      <td>${data[i].sc_fullname}</td><td>${data[i].sc_email}</td><td>${data[i].sc_mobile_no}</td><td>${data[i].role}</td><td>${data[i].status}</td></tr>`;
                   for (let j = 0; j < data[i].payement_detail.length; j++){
                       html+=`<tr>
                                 <td colspan="5">
                                  <table class="table table-bordered">
                                   <td>p1: ${(data[i].payement_detail[j].p1 != null) ? data[i].payement_detail[j].p1 : ''}</td>
                                   <td>p2:${(data[i].payement_detail[j].p2 != null) ? data[i].payement_detail[j].p2 : ''}</td>
                                   <td>p3:${(data[i].payement_detail[j].p3 != null) ? data[i].payement_detail[j].p3 : ''}</td>
                                   <td>p4:${(data[i].payement_detail[j].p4 != null) ? data[i].payement_detail[j].p4 : ''}</td>
                                   <td>p5:${(data[i].payement_detail[j].p5 != null) ? data[i].payement_detail[j].p5 : ''}</td>
                                   <td>p6:${(data[i].payement_detail[j].p6 != null) ? data[i].payement_detail[j].p6 : ''}</td>
                                   <td>p7:${(data[i].payement_detail[j].p7 != null) ? data[i].payement_detail[j].p7 : ''}</td>
                                   <td>p8:${(data[i].payement_detail[j].p8 != null) ? data[i].payement_detail[j].p8 : ''}</td>
                                   <td>p9:${(data[i].payement_detail[j].p9 != null) ? data[i].payement_detail[j].p9 : ''}</td>
                                   <td>p10:${(data[i].payement_detail[j].p10 != null) ? data[i].payement_detail[j].p10 : ''}</td>
                                   <td>p11:${(data[i].payement_detail[j].p11 != null) ? data[i].payement_detail[j].p11 : ''}</td>
                                   <td>p12:${(data[i].payement_detail[j].p12 != null) ? data[i].payement_detail[j].p12 : ''}</td>
                                   <a style="display: none;" href="/admin/edit-member-payment-detail/${data[i].payement_detail[j].id}">Edit</a>
                                  </table>
                                  </td>
                       </tr>`;
                   }
               }
               html += `</table></div>`
               $('#search-fetched').empty().append(html);
               $('#prefetched').hide();
           });
       } else {
           $('#prefetched').show();
           $("#search-fetched").empty();
       }
   })
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".tableshow").click(function(){
           $(".collapseshow").toggle();
       });
   });
</script>
```